Content Security Policy nonce Inline Style attribute not working HTML
Trying to implement CSP with nonce attribute along with style attribute.
Note: Already tried with Header via Server but error is same in Google Chrome Version 123.0.6312.86 (Official Build) (64-bit).
below is equivalent html of same.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' 'nonce-kiddo'">
    <title>Sample HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="color: red;" nonce="kiddo">This text will be red.</div>
</body>
</html>

Error in Chrome

A nonce can be used in nonceable elements, which applies to script and style tags.
For elements with inline styles, a nonce won't work directly. Inline styles should be moved to a style block or an external CSS file.
